# Why does water freeze radial around an object?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ice

I noticed an interesting fact today while having a popsicle during my lunch break. When I bit the top of, I could see that in the freezer the ice had frozen radial around the stick. Could anybody explain the physics behind that to me, please?

Comment: When you say, "frozen radial," are you attempting to describe the orientation of visible ice crystals with respect to the stick?

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to say. Can you explain that process to me?

Comment: No, but I can upvote your question. I've seen the same thing, and have wondered about it myself.

Answer (score 0):

as you chill water below its freezing point, it wants to freeze but cannot do so until it is presented with what are called *nucleation seed sites* which trigger the phase change. In this case, the seed site has to resemble a tiny bit of solid ice, upon which the nearby supercooled water molecules can coalesce.

In the popsicle case, the seed sites are provided in the crevices of the wooden popsicle stick which means the crystallization of the water into ice begins at the surface of the stick and progresses *radially outwards*. The crystal shapes therefore become elongated and skinny, with their tips pointing backwards towards the seed site on the surface of the stick where they were "born".